# Is there a term for the words whose stress is on the first syllable?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that oxytone, paroxytone, and proparoxytone mean that its stress is on the last, penultimate, and antepenultimate syllable, respectively. Does a term for those having it on the first exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [prototonic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prototonic), meaning a word accented on the first syllable.  Additionally, there is the term [deuterotonic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deuterotonic), which indicates an accent on the second syllable.

[Mitch's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/496786/133915) describes terminology from poetic meter rather than technical linguistic terms.  For anyone looking for terms in that regard, his information is correct.

Answer (score 3):

A two-syllable word with the stress on the first syllable is called a

> [trochee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee).

Words like 'double', 'parent', and 'major' are trochees. There are a lot more examples in this [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/856/).

This is in distinction to an [iamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)), with the stress on the second syllable, for example: 'police', 'manure', 'alive'.

'Trochee' isn't exactly what you're looking for since it describes only two syllable words, and you're looking for a word with *any* number of syllables where the accent is on the first. ([**anapest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapaest) is for three syllable words.) Also, these terms are mostly used for poetic *meter*, irrespective of word boundaries, but they still are often applied to standalone words.

One would expect, by analogy with the Greek system, that

> prototone

would be the word (proto- = first) but is not listed in the OED. It is [sometimes used though](https://books.google.com/books?pg=PT121&q=prototone+first+syllable&source=bl):

> It is generally agreed ... that preclassical Latin was prototone: stress the initial syllable.

Comment: "Trochee" is a term used to describe meter in poetry.  This is not the correct context for the question, which is asking about linguistic terms.

Comment: Also, proterotone isn't a word, but you're thinking on the right track.  I would think the correct noun form might be "prototerone," but that doesn't seem to be an established word, either.  In any case, the correct term the poster is looking for is prototonic.